# I am afraid of dark

Tags: questions

It was raining yesterday.

Suddenly a loud thunder strikes and lights off.

**"I am afraid of dark."**

**"I am scare of dark."**

What are the different between them?

Comment: It should be "I am afraid of **the** dark." and "I am scare**d** of **the** dark."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afraid and scared are synonyms of each other, which means that they have similar meanings. They can be used interchangeably. The subtle difference between "scare" and "afraid" is that "scare" is a verb and "afraid" is an adjective. A better and *more correct* way of writing the second sentence would be:

> I am **scared** of the dark.

Answer (score 1):

Both your sentences are incorrect simply because they lack the definite article "**the**". **Afraid** as an adjective that means **"feeling fear"**. We use it with **of + noun**, **of + -ing form**, a **to-infinitive** or a **that-clause**:

- I am *afraid* **of the dark**

**Scared** can act both as a transitive and an intransitive verb. However, the second sounds much closer to my non-native ear. The first example is in the *passive voice* and the second one is in the *active voice*:

- I am scared of the dark. *(Passive - Present Indefinite)*
- The dark scares me. *(Active- Present Indefinite)*

I would also consider using the word "**darkness**" that may come without "**the**". However, it's a matter of choice.

- I am afraid of darkness
- Darkness scares me.

Comment: Hey, *The* is definite article :) Btw, Imo, I think "scared" is an adjective in "I am scared of the dark".